# Is it possible to configure multiple floppy drives in Hyper-v?

Tags: hyper-v

I need to test something in a hyper-v instance where two floppy drives need to be present. I can configure the existing one to a .vfd. But I need to replicate a machine that has two floppy drives.

I could not see anything in my searches that mentioned creating another floppy drive. Is the one that is available by default the sole one that can be used?

Answer (score 0):

Did you say "floppy" drive, in case you meant CD/DVD or floppyyou can always use software that emulates removable disk drive. Magic Disk will do CD/DVD and Virtual Floppy Disk will do Floppy drive.